# How to map multiple data rows to different fields

Tags: java, database, querydsl

I'm trying to use querydsl and projection to map the results of a query onto an object.

I have something like the following:

```
public record DataTransferObject(MyTable obj1, MyTable obj2) {
    public static final ConstructorExpression<DataTransferObject> PROJECTION = 
        Projections.constructor(obj1, obj2);
}

@Service
public class QueryService {
    private final JPQLQueryFactory queryFactory;

    public DataTransferObject getData(String id1, String id2) {
        return queryFactory.select(DataTransferObject.PROJECTION)
            .from(QMyTable.myTable)
            .where(QMyTable.myTable.id.eq(id1)
                .or(QMyTable.myTable.id.eq(id2))
            .fetchOne();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work as I run into `com.querydsl.core.NonUniqueResultException`.

Using joins like in the following results in obj1 and obj2 being the same object (even though the 2 ids map to 2 unique rows):

```
.leftJoin(QMyTable.myTable)
    .on(QMyTable.myTable.id.eq(id1))
.leftJoin(QMyTable.myTable)
    .on(QMyTable.myTable.id.eq(id2))
```

I want to match DB row corresponding to `String id1` to the `MyTable obj1` field in the `DataTransferObject` object. Similarly, I want to match DB row corresponding to `String id2` to the `MyTable obj2` field in the `DataTransferObject` object.

What's a preferable/best way to accomplish this?

Comment: why don't you use join clause?

Comment: how would that work?

Comment: @bananas I ask because when I do something like

.leftJoin(QMyTable.myTable)
    .on(QMyTable.myTable.id.eq(id1))
.leftJoin(QMyTable.myTable)
    .on(QMyTable.myTable.id.eq(id2))

both obj1 and obj2 end up being the same object. I'll update the post.

Comment: Your query is returning multiple results and fetchOne expects a unique result, that's why you're getting an exception, try to fetch everything instead of expecting a single result. use `fetchFirst` or `fetchAll` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I preemptively defining the objects worked. It's working with something like:

```
@Service
public class QueryService {
    private static final QMyTable OBJ1 = new QMyTable("obj1");
    private static final QMyTable OBJ2 = new QMyTable("obj2");

    public static final ConstructorExpression<DataTransferObject> PROJECTION = Projections.constructor(
        MyTable.projection(OBJ1),
        MyTable.projection(OBJ2)
    );

    private final JPQLQueryFactory queryFactory;

    public DataTransferObject getData(String id1, String id2) {
        return queryFactory.select(PROJECTION)
            .from(QMyTable.myTable)
            .leftJoin(OBJ1)
                    .on(OBJ1.id.eq(id1))
            .leftJoin(OBJ2)
                    .on(OBJ2.id.eq(id2))
            .fetchOne();
    }
}
```

Left some stuff out, but that's the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing fetchOne() to fetchFirst() or fetchAll()

Comment: fetchFirst() resolves the issue of the NonUniqueResultException, but I end up with both obj1 and obj2 as the same object (I presume whatever fetchFirst() returned).

I'm not sure how to use fetchAll() here :(